# IF ELSE in postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, postgresql-12

I am trying to create a function which is as follows

```
create function public.getSomething(
        value1 integer
    )
      returns table (
             id integer,
             name varchar(20)
    
              ) as
    $$
    BEGIN
    
        IF value1 = 0 THEN
        
            select a.id, b.name from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.Something = b.Something where 
            a.column = something and b.column = something;
            
        END IF;
    
        IF value1 = 1 THEN
        
            select a.id, b.name from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.Something = b.Something where 
            a.column = something and b.column = something;
            
        END IF;
    
    END;
            
    $$ language SQL;
```

But when I am trying to Create, I am getting the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"
```

I tried changing the Language from SQL to plpgsql. But this time I am getting

```
Error: query has no destination for result data
Hint: if you want to discard the results of a select use perform instead
```

then I replaced the `Select` with `Perform`. This time the function is created but when I am calling it
There is no result!!

What am I doing wrong? Is there any alternative? I am Using postgres version 12.3

Comment: `if .. else` can only be used in PL/pgSQL, not in SQL. In PL/pgSQL, you need `return query select ..` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function with slight modifications (in capitals):

1. Language *is* plpgsql;
2. In a SQL function you simply return the result of a query. In a plpgsql function you have to use `RETURN` statement to return anything. As you do not want to discard the query results but return them, add `RETURN QUERY` before the SELECT statements.

```sql
create OR REPLACE function public.getSomething(value1 integer)
returns table (id integer, name varchar(20)) as
$$
    BEGIN

        IF value1 = 0 THEN
            RETURN QUERY select a.id, b.name from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.Something = b.Something where 
            a.column = something and b.column = something;
        END IF;

        IF value1 = 1 THEN
            RETURN QUERY select a.id, b.name from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.Something = b.Something where 
            a.column = something and b.column = something;
        END IF;

    END;
            
$$ language PLPGSQL;
```